# How to get my list of values inside my key dict and this one is a value for the first key

Tags: python

I got this dict

```
{'2022-09-08T15:00:00Z': {'BRASILIA': [{'value': '95.0', 'quality': 'qf-GOOD', 'quality_flag': 'GOOD', 'structure': 'BRASILIA', 'element': 'DVENTO'}, {'value': '6.0', 'quality': 'qf-UNCHECKED', 'quality_flag': 'UNCHECKED', 'structure': 'BRASILIA', 'element': 'TD_MN_C'}]}}
```

I want to get the list inside the "BRASILIA" key, how to do this?
can I group by this?

EDIT 1: I want to do this without calling Brasilia key, something like dict["BRASILIA"]

Comment: sorry, I didn't specify that I didn't want it without calling the keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one datetime key, you can do:

```
yourdict.get(next(iter(a)), {}).get("BRASILIA")
```

Edit: without calling any key, first idea i have is to use something like this:

```
first_key = next(iter(your_dict))
data = your_dict.get(first_key, {})
country_name = next(iter(data))
output = data.get(country_name)
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't specify that I didn't want it without calling the keys

Comment: I've updated my answer with an idea